# How to subset and modify in pandas like "which" in R?

Tags: r, pandas

I have written an R script in which i am using which to subset data and assign changes

```
i <- "132_list"
t <- which(dat_unique$x == list1[i])
dat_unique$size_diff[t] <- size_diff
```

I am implementing similar script in python but not able to do so:

```
i = "132_list"
dat_unique[dat_unique.x == i]["size_diff"] = size_diff
```

It is not getting modified

i is the value of some variable in column x.

By running only this I am able to get subseeted dataframe but not able to modify it

```
dat_unique[dat_unique.x == i]
```

Comment: please include some sample and expected data for testing

Comment: What is `i` in the python.  It is not initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use .loc-based indexing.

```
dat_unique.loc[dat_unique.x == i,'size_diff'] = size_diff;
```

This of course works only if size_diff is the same size as there are values of same value as i in dat_unique.x.